# How do I get my child class to show within it's prospective parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, rails-api

I was hoping to get a little bit of help here. I'm working on a project and I can't seem to the the data to show as I'd like it to. I have a playlist that can have many tracks. I have access to both on the page but I cannot seem to get tracks inside of the prospective playlists. I'm guessing it has something to do with the element but I'm not 100% as I am a little but new to JS. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
   

     class Track {
     
        constructor(track, trackAttributes) {  
            this.id = track.id
            this.artist = trackAttributes.artist
            this.title = trackAttributes.title
            Track.all.push(this);
           
        }
      
        renderTrackCard() {
            return  `  
             <div data-id=${this.id}>          
             <h3><li>Track Artist: ${this.artist}</h3></li>
             <h3><li>Track Title: ${this.title}</h3></li>       
             </div> </li>
             `
             ;            
        } 
    }
    
    Track.all = [];
    
    class Playlist {
     
      constructor(playlist, playlistAttributes) {    
         this.id = playlist.id
         this.name = playlistAttributes.name  
         Playlist.all.push(this);   
    }
    
    renderPlaylistCard() {
      return  `            
       <div data-id=${this.id}>
       <h3><li>Playlist Name: ${this.name}</h3></li> 
       <button data-id=${this.id}>EDIT!</button>    
       </div> </li>
       `
          ;  
     }
    }  
    
    Playlist.all = [];
    
    const BACKEND_URL = "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/playlists"
    const tracks_URL =  "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tracks"
    
    
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      getPlaylists(); 
      getTracks();
    
      const createPlaylistForm = document.getElementById("create-playlist-form")
      createPlaylistForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => createFormHandler(e))  
    })
    
     
    
    function getPlaylists() {
  fetch(BACKEND_URL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(playlist  => {
       playlist.data.map((playlist, index)  =>  {      
          let newPlaylist = new Playlist(playlist, playlist.attributes);

      // playlist.attributes.tracks[index].title +=  playlist.attributes.tracks[index].artist 
       console.log(playlist.attributes.name)
       console.log(playlist.attributes.tracks[index].title)
       console.log(playlist.attributes.tracks[index].artist)
**THIS CODE WORKS IN THE CONSOLE BUT IF I RETURN IT, IT DOES NOTHING. BASICALLY I NEED THIS ON THE PAGE AND NOT IN THE CONSOLE BUT I CAN'T SEEM TO MAKE THAT HAPPEN.** 
        
       document.getElementById('playlist-container').innerHTML +=  newPlaylist.renderPlaylistCard();  
    
        })
       
        }
  )
}
    
    function getTracks() {
      fetch(tracks_URL)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(trk  => {
              trk.data.forEach(track =>   { 
                          
              let newTrack = new Track(track, track.attributes);
              let withTracks = []
              withTracks.push(track.attributes.artist, track.attributes.title)
    
              
              document.getElementById('tracks-container').innerHTML += newTrack.renderTrackCard();   
              }
          )}
      )
    }
    
         
        function createFormHandler(e) {
          e.preventDefault()
          const nameInput = document.getElementById('input-name').value
          const playlistId = parseInt(document.getElementById('tracks').value)
       
    
        }
    
        function postFetch(name, playlist_id){
        fetch(BACKEND_URL, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"},
          body: JSON.stringify({
            name: name,
            playlist_id: playlist_id,
          })      
        })    
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(playlist => {          
          const playlistData = playlist.data;      
          let newPlaylist = new Playlist(playlistData, playlistData.attributes);
        
          document.getElementById('tracks-container').innerHTML += newPlaylist.renderPlaylistCard() ;
       
        })  
      }
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>   
        <script type="application/javascript" src="src/index.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="src/playlist.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="src/track.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    
    
    
      </head>
      <body style="background-color: cyan;">
    
        <div class="form-container">
          <h1>Create a Playlist!</h1>
          <form id="create-playlist-form"  >
            <input id="input-name" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Playlist Name">
            <input id="artist-value" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Artist Name">
            <!-- <input id="tracks" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Track Name"> -->
            <input id="title-value" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Track Title">   
              
    
            <p> Choose Tracks! </p>
              <select id="tracks" name="tracks" autofocus>
                <option value="4">First</option>
                <option value="5">Second</option>
                <option value="1">Third</option> 
                <option value="2">Fourth</option> 
                <option value="3">Hip Hop Horray</option> 
                </select>
    
              </form>
           <!-- <input id="artist-name" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Artist Name"> -->
             <input id="create-button" type ="submit" name="submit" value="Create Playlist" class="submit"> 
             <div class="full-playlist">
              <h1> Current Playlists;</h1>
            
                <div id="tracks-container">
                 
    
               
           
    
          
        </div>
      </div>
          
         </body> 
      </html>
```

Comment: Hey @Randy, can you edit your code and mark the line that's not working with a comment like `<THIS ISN'T WORKING>` because it is quite difficult to understand the problem here.
Can you please explain which value you expect as which line of code?

Comment: Hey @mjzeus I updated so hopefully that helps. My issue is in the index.js file in the getPlaylists function. If you see the console.log's that is what i'm needing on the page but I can't seem to get that to happen although it is working properly in the console. My map inside of this function is only returning  the first instance currently. ```Country Songs
index.js:23 Fourth Song
index.js:24 Kristy
index.js:22 Pop Songs
index.js:23 Hip Hop Horray
index.js:24 Randy```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just missing the element with the id `playlist-container`.

Can you try changing your HTML from this

```
<div class="full-playlist">
    <h1> Current Playlists;</h1>
    <div id="tracks-container"></div>
</div>
```

to this

```
<div class="full-playlist">
    <h1> Current Playlists;</h1>
    <div id="playlist-container"></div>
    <div id="tracks-container"></div>
</div>
```

I suppose that should solve your problem. I hope that helps.

Comment: hmmm I am still getting the same result.

Comment: It seems like the map is only giving me access to the first iterations. do you see any issues with the code there?
```function getPlaylists() {
  fetch(BACKEND_URL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(playlist  => {
       playlist.data.map((playlist, index)  =>  {      
          let newPlaylist = new Playlist(playlist, playlist.attributes);

        })
        
       
        }
  )
}
@mjzeus